# Azure active DirectoryTenantID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

While generating a token we are passing tenant id in the token en point URL

is it necessary to add?
please find the below URL
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ tenantId;
Can we share tenantId while generating token to client?

will it not create any security problems

Is there any alternative

I have found "common"  but when i am giving that one it is raising an error

Could any one provide sample example by using "common" instead of tenantid ?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenant id is just an identifier that uniquely identifies your AAD tenant.
It is not a secret, and can be easily found.

You use it in the authority URL when you want to authenticate against a specific tenant.
Common is for multi-tenant apps which allow authentication with any tenant.

Comment: @ Juunas but when i am specifying common instead of tenant it is raising an error

I am specifying common like below

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
please find the below error

One or more errors occurred. (AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.
Trace ID: 24cd7f6c-69e6-452e-bf11-ae6f1fa12d00
Correlation ID: 9d5be18c-4970-4a9c-8af7-c0dda18b2e23
Timestamp: 2019-03-07 13:02:24Z)

Comment: Yeah, you may have to specify the tenant id in certain situations, common is mainly used when authenticating users via redirects or pop-ups

Comment: Is there any sample code with "common" for generating token with azure active drectory using c#
It will help full

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?